# Spring: Get inline bean by name

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I would like to get inner bean by it's name. Is it possible with Spring API?

Right now I'm using such Spring 2.5 API

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext.getBean(String paramString)
```

Example of XML:

```
<bean id="parent" parent="t_Parent">
    <property name="items">
        <bean id="child" parent="t_Child">
            <property name="ABC" value="test"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would like to get inner (t_Child) bean by id "child". E.g. ConfigurableApplicationContext.getBean("child"). Spring can't find such bean (because it's inner). At the same time .getBean("parent") works fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

From [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-inner-beans):

> A  element inside the  or  elements is used to define a so-called inner bean. An inner bean definition does not need to have any id or name defined, and it is best not to even specify any id or name value **because the id or name value simply will be ignored by the container**.

If you need it like that, define it as a regular bean.

Comment: BeanNameAware - maybe, but you can't use that to access the bean, can you?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but you can create you inner bean outside (so it's no longer an inner bean...) and then reference it inside the property:

```
<bean id="child" parent="t_Child">
    <property name="ABC" value="test"/>
</bean>

<bean id="parent" parent="t_Parent">
    <property name="items" ref="child"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Why not so convenient ? In that way if you want to reference it two or more times you can, and if you need to retrieve an inner bean why not using parent corresponding property ?

Comment: Depends of the size of your configuration. When it's huge you would like to merge beans as much as possible.

Comment: If file size is the issue why not splitting configuration in multiple files ? you can use 'import' to merge them.

Comment: You can put what was your inner bean in a dedicated xml file that you import at the begin of your main file ... ;-)

Comment: You know, it's always a tradeoff between readability, simplicity and a real life. When I really need to reuse inner beans I would promote them to "standard" beans, othrerwise I would like to follow KISS principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other (mostly valid) answers and solutions, I guess the spring way would be to use the `BeanWrapper` interface:

```
final BeanWrapper bw =
    new BeanWrapperImpl(applicationContext.getBean("parent"));
Object innerBean = bw.getPropertyValue("child");
```

But I guess that implies that there must be a getter for the property (not only a setter).

**Reference:**

- [BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html) (javadoc, 2.5 version)
- [Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans) (reference, 2.5 version)

Answer (score 0):

If you move up to Spring 3.x, you should be able to do this with the Spring Expression Language.  There are examples of directly referencing a bean property from another property (like in [link text](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/spring_3_0_expression_language)).  The code to do this from Java would be somewhat similar, although I can't find an exact example of this scenario.

However, I would say that if you're trying to use "getBean()", you're doing something wrong.  You could just as easily use the SpEL in your context to define a bean or a bean property that references that inner bean.